# Multi-line footer alignment

Tags: fancyhdr

### Problem

I am trying to **align a one-line right footer to the last line of a four-lines center one**.

My current solution is to force line breaks using `\- \\` three times before the actual page numbering. I also have to account for font size differences so I end up with `\small{\-} \\ \scriptsize \- \\ \- \\` managing the vertical space.

Not only does this appear extremely inefficient and *wrong* but since the fourth lines of each footer are not of the same size, it is not looking quite nice.

[image: fancyhdr footer]

### Bonus question

Why is it that in the screenshot the fourth line (4) is not properly centered with the others?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, draft, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{
  \centering
  \small{1} \\
  \scriptsize
  2 \\
  3 \\
  4
}
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a `tabular` environment.

```
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \scriptsize
  \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
  \small 1 \\
  2 \\
  3 \\
  4
  \end{tabular}%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
\fancyfoot[C]{
  \centering\footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}[b]{c}%
  1 \\
  2 \\
  3 \\
  4
\end{tabular}
}
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `\Longstack`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, draft, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{
  \centering\scriptsize\Longstack{\small 1\\2\\3\\4}%
}
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works as expected, thanks. I do, however, prefer the `tabular` solution as it appears simpler.